# Word for "intersection of human and nature" or "human-nature relations"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I already know that "anthropology" refers to mankind and "ecology" or something like that can refer to nature, but I was wondering if there was a fancy word that meant something along the lines of the intersection of human and nature.

There probably isn't, but this is worth a shot.

Sample: "On the topic of [word], King states that [insert long quote here]"

Comment: You can search _human ecology_, _ecological anthropology_ and _anthroecology_.

Comment: Note that using "human-nature relations" would be confusing to your readers, since "human nature" is a (different) "thing".

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *intersection* in this context. The sample sentence doesn't clarify this. Are you talking about people changing the environment, or people as part of an environment, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

How about "Ethnography"?

A quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnography) says:

> The typical ethnography is a holistic study and so includes a brief history, and an analysis of the terrain, the climate, and the habitat. In all cases, it should be reflexive, make a substantial contribution toward the understanding of the social life of humans, have an aesthetic impact on the reader, and express a credible reality. An ethnography records all observed behavior and describes all symbol-meaning relations, using concepts that avoid causal explanations. Traditionally, ethnography was focussed on the western gaze towards the far 'exotic' east, but now researchers are undertaking ethnography in their own social environment.

Answer (score 0):

"Anthropocene" is the term used by anthropologists to denote the era in which human behaviour is the most dominant factor in shaping the environment.